# jquery - html() of variable option with multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

I'm not quite sure if I am doing this right, as I am no jquery pro.
But here are the facts:
I need all the #box in my kontinent[i].content as html code appeded to the previous html in the #content div.
This seems to work just fine at first, but when I look closely, only the first element (eg. "#box1" in europe.content is appended and I don't understand why.

Do I have to loop through the elements selected by kontinent[i].content?

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
    var europa = {
        content: $( '#box1,#box5,#box6,#box7,#box8,#box9,#box10,#box13,#box18,#box19,#box20,#box21,#box23,#box25,#box27,#box28,#box32,#box33,#box37' ),
        name: "europa"
        };
    var usa1 = {
        content: $( '#box38' ),
        name: "usa1"
        };
    var usa2 = {
        content: $( '#box3,#box17' ),
        name: "usa2"
        };
    var afr = {
        content: $( '#box29' ),
        name: "afr"
        };
    var asi = {
        content: $( '#box4,#box11,#box12,#box14,#box15,#box16,#box22,#box24,#box26,#box30,#box31,#box34,#box35,#box36' ),
        name: "asi"
        };
    var aus = {
        content: $( '#box2' ),
        name: "aus"
        };

    var kontinent = [europa, usa1, usa2, afr, asi, aus];
    var content = $('#content');
    var precon = content.html();
    var i = 0;

    $('#world-weltkartelinks a').click( function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        i = 0;

        while ( i <= 5 ) {
            if ($(this).attr('data-region') == kontinent[i].name) {
                content.html(precon + kontinent[i].content.html());
            };
            i++;
        };
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much you can change the setup of your code it might work better to have a main object, eliminating the need to loop in the first place, similar to his:

```
var regions = {
    europa: {
        content: $('#box1,#box5,#box6,#box7,#box8,#box9,#box10,#box13,#box18,#box19,#box20,#box21,#box23,#box25,#box27,#box28,#box32,#box33,#box37')
    },
    usa1: {
        content: $('#box38')
    }
};
```

The benefit now is that you can access the kontinent without looping through it. However, to get the `html` content of all selectors in your `content` property you still need a loop though. similar to this:

```
var kontinent = regions;
var content = $('#content');
var precon = content.html();

$('#world-weltkartelinks a').click( function( event ) {
    var region = $(this).attr('data-region')

    if (kontinent[region]) { // no more looping needed
        var allBoxes = '';

        $(kontinent[region].content).each(function () { // still needs to loop to extract all HTML values for all selectors.
            return allBoxes += this.innerHTML;
        });

        content.html(precon + allBoxes);
    }
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/H7TY5/) - Using an object instead of an array

---

The demo is using a scaled down version as I don't have your actual HTML to see a working demo of using the main object:

```
var regions = {
    europa: {
        content: $('#box1,#box5,#box6,#box7,#box8,#box9,#box10,#box13,#box18,#box19,#box20,#box21,#box23,#box25,#box27,#box28,#box32,#box33,#box37')
    },
    usa1: {
        content: $('#box38')
    }
};

var kontinent = regions;
var content = $('#content');
var precon = content.html();

var region = 'europa';
if (kontinent[region]) {
    var allBoxes = '';

    $(kontinent[region].content).each(function () {
        return allBoxes += this.innerHTML;
    });

    content.html(precon + allBoxes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, showed me things I did not know about. But I still got this error, that there is just the first box of the element (eg europa) appended? Like only #box1 gets appended to the content, the rest does not.

Comment: @samtun: This MDN page on [**Working with Objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) shows how you can access objects with either dot-notation , i.e: `object.propertyName` or access them as "associative arrays" i.e: object["propertyName"], which works as each object property is associated with a string value. In regards to the missing appended data, I didn't realise you wanted all of them, my bad. Sorry about that. In that case looping might not be avoided. I have a look again though.

Comment: Okay, but thanks so far at first! This reduced my code alot and made me dig deeper into the use of objects.

Comment: @samtun: I hope I understood you right. I edited the code to get the `html` content of all the element selectors specified in the `content` property of the matched kontinent. You can improve the code from her as you need to.

Comment: I changed the objects data just giving them the numbers in an array `conent: [1,2,3...]`, then looped through with `content.append($('#box' + regions[region].content[o]).html());` this did the trick. I would like to post this as answer here, but I am not allowed due to a lack of reputation points right now. Anyway, if anyone has improvements to this, please tell me, I am still learning. Thanks to Francois, saw your edit right now, seems like that works too. great!

Comment: @samtun: Nice alternative. The only suggestion I have is **not** to always write directly to a reference located in the DOM but instead write to a variable and write only the final result to the element in the DOM. Reason being is that multiple calls to update the DOM (i.e: `append()`) can cause slow rendering of the page if you have a lot of items. So, instead; outside the loop declare: `var newHTML = '';` in the loop append to the variable: `newHTML += $('#box' + regions[region].content[o]).html();` and after the loop write the final result to the DOM: `content.append(newHTML)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var $current = $(this);
    $.each(kontinent,function(idx,element){
      if ($current.attr('data-region') == element.name) {
                    content.append(element.content.html());
      }
    };
```

Notice that you can use `append` to keep your initial content without having to insert it again.